# Custom Android Emulators

Tags: android-emulator, android

I currently have an Android app on the Android Market.  One of it's main purposes involves detecting incoming calls.  Unfortunately, some phone models don't seem to be detecting this correctly.  The version of Android isn't the problem (other phones with 2.1 and 2.2 work fine), so I'm wondering if the phones have something unique about them.

Because the main phone I've had problems with is the Epic 4g, I was hoping to get an emulator running simulating the phone.  Is it possible to do this?  I don't know anyone that personally has that model of phone, so this seems like my only option to debug the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this for [Motorola Phones](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Installing_the_Motorola_SDK_Add-on/)
which has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the emulator is based on QEMU, so it can be configured deeply. But thats not very useful as it is hard to get the actual hardware specs of any specific device as long it's developing company don't like to talk and share their secrets and flaws. 
This said, it would be quite easy for an phone company insider to set up an exact emulator but very hacker style to set up for ourselves, needing days of investigation on the actual phone to check out its hardware details.